# One way connections and "n degrees of seperation" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, graph

I have a table of entities with integer IDs, let's call it Entities. In another table, I have one way relationships between these entities by having a column for "From", "To" and what kind of relationship they have (let's call this table Relationships). Entities might be "two way" by having two corresponding one way relationships and the overall thing is a graph or web.

I'm looking to write a routine where I can pass it an Entity ID and how many degrees of separation to go and it returns every entity ID within that many relationships of the passed ID. I have no idea how to write this routine. The iterative nature of this is beyond my experience with stored procedures. Any clues how to start this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table relationships with columns from_id and to_id

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS find_relationships;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE find_relationships( start_id int(11), level int(11) )
BEGIN
  DECLARE found INT(11) DEFAULT 1;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS related_entities;
  CREATE TABLE related_entities (id int(11) PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=HEAP;
  INSERT INTO related_entities VALUES ( start_id );
  WHILE found > 0 AND level > 0 DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO related_entities
      SELECT DISTINCT from_id FROM relationships r
      JOIN related_entities rf ON r.to_id = rf.id 
      UNION 
      SELECT DISTINCT to_id FROM relationships r
      JOIN related_entities rf ON r.from_id = rf.id;
    SET found = ROW_COUNT();
    SET level = level - 1;
  END WHILE;
  SELECT * FROM related_entities;
  DROP TABLE related_entities;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Should work for any graph, finding all connected nodes within distance given as level.

```
call find_relationships( 5, 2 );
```

Comment: I really look forward to trying this out. I'll write back this afternoon with my results.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `with` statements in MySQL, so you'll need a temporary table. Pseudo-code:

```
drop table if exists tmp_nodes;

create temporary table tmp_nodes as
select :id as id;

while :depth++ < :max_depth
  insert into tmp_nodes
  select links.id
  from links
  join tmp_nodes as nodes on nodes.id = links.parent_id
  left join tmp_nodes as cycle on cycle.id = links.id
  where cycle.id is null;

select id from tmp_nodes optionally where id <> :id;
```

---

Looks like piotrm wrote the needed function for you.